# Embedding Python in C++ libraries

Tags: c++, python, linker, embedding

I'm working on embedding Python in some C++ code, but I'm getting stuck compiling it.

For a header file, I have

```
#include <Python.h>
```

I would initial try,

```
$g++ EmbeddedPython.cpp
```

but would end up getting

```
EmbeddedPython.cpp:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
EmbeddedPython.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
EmbeddedPython.cpp:6: error: ‘Py_Initialize’ was not declared in this scope
....
```

I then tried

```
g++ EmbeddedPython.cpp -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5
```

and that got rid of the first two errors, but I still ended up with

```
 Undefined symbols:
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
  _main in ccxJAUAB.o
```

I'm a bit of new to this, but I think I'm learning fast. I believe I need to 'Link' a library, right?  But which one and how? Do I need a dynamic or a static one?

I am working on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: Also I have a macbook pro, python2.5, python2.6 and python2.7.

Comment: got I added /usr/lib/libpython.dylib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link against libpython. UNIX programmers do this with "-lpython" in the link command (ie at the end of that "g++" command). On a Mac, I think it would be "-framework Python".

Comment: That worked thanks.  Is there something else I can type so that I don't have to type -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5

Comment: I don't know exactly what Apple's gcc does with frameworks. If "-framework Python" didn't take care of that, then I think you're stuck with what you have there.

Comment: For newer versions of python it should be "-lpythonX.Y" where X.Y is the python version. For example, for python 3.8 it should be "-lpython3.8".